# Google Play Campaign not working after the Application released on Playstore

Tags: android

I have follow google official link :-

https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/testing-play-campaigns

My manifest look like :

```
   <service
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService"
        android:enabled="true" />
```

I also received the following message in logcat.

[image]

but when i released the application to playstore after integration, i am not able to track the downloads on google analytics.

I have used this link to download the application, created with Google Play URL Builder

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.audecibel&referrer=utm_source%3Demail

Please Help if anybody used Campaign tracking in their applications.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Post complete log cat?

Comment: check my updated post @Shailesh